# Dymola 2012 Output Interval behavior

Tags: modelica, dymola

When I set the Output Interval of a simulation Dymola I expect to receive **Number Of Intervals** + 1 data points in the .mat file.  This is not the case, why?

Reviewing the [Dymola 2012 User Manual](http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/cellier/Lect/MMPS/Refs/Dymola5Manual.pdf):

**Output Interval** to specify how often results shall be stored.  It can be specified in terms of **Interval length** or **Number of Intervals** for the simulation.  By default the results are also stored at discrete events.

I assume the discrepancy between expectation and what is produced has to do with the storage of discrete events.  If this is right, how can I turn this function off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my version of Dymola (2015), there is an option in the Output tab: Store variables at events. Uncheck that box if it is available in Dymola 2012.